# Using SnapSVGAnimator extension for Adobe Animate CC... how can I get the SVGdom into a particular div?

Tags: json, ajax, flash-cs5, snap.svg, adobe-edge

I'm not very familiar with ajax and json, but that is how the code is generated with the extension.

Here is what is outputted...

```
        <script src="./SnapSVGAnimator/js/vendor/snap.svg/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
        <script src="./SnapSVGAnimator/js/SnapSVGAnimator.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var jsonfile = "test.json",
                fps = 24,
                width = 1000,
                height = 1000,
                AJAX_req;

        AJAX_JSON_Req(jsonfile);

        function handle_AJAX_Complete() {
            if( AJAX_req.readyState == 4 && AJAX_req.status == 200 )
            {
                json = JSON.parse(AJAX_req.responseText);
                comp = new SVGAnim(
                               json,
                               width,
                               height,
                               fps
                               );

            }
        }

        function AJAX_JSON_Req( url )
        {
            AJAX_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            AJAX_req.open("GET", url, true);
            AJAX_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            AJAX_req.onreadystatechange = handle_AJAX_Complete;
            AJAX_req.send();
        }

                </script>
```

and here is the JSON

```
    {
        "DOMDocument" : {
            "Shape" : [
                {
                    "charid" : "1",
                    "path" : [
                        {
                            "color" : "#0066cc",
                            "colorOpacity" : "1",
                            "d" : "M 92.15 92.15 q 15.85 -15.8 15.85 -38.15 q 0 -22.35 -15.85 -38.2 q -15.8 -15.8 -38.15 -15.8 q -22.35 0 -38.2 15.8 q -15.8 15.85 -15.8 38.2 q 0 22.35 15.8 38.15 q 15.85 15.85 38.2 15.85 q 22.35 0 38.15 -15.85 ",
                            "pathType" : "Fill",
                            "stroke" : "none"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Bitmaps" : [],
            "Sounds" : [],
            "Text" : [],
            "Timeline" : [
                {
                    "charid" : "2",
                    "frameCount" : "1",
                    "name" : "Ball",
                    "Frame" : [
                        {
                            "num" : "0",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Place",
                                    "charid" : "1",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "placeAfter" : "0",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1,0,0,1,0,0"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "frameCount" : "35",
                    "Frame" : [
                        {
                            "num" : "0",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Place",
                                    "charid" : "2",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "placeAfter" : "0",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1,0,0,1,177,212.95",
                                    "name" : "Ball"
                                },
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "UpdateColorTransform",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "colorMatrix" : "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,"
                                },
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "UpdateVisibility",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "visibility" : "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "UpdateBlendMode",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "blendMode" : "Normal"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "1",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.08363,0,0,1.08366,187.65312,224.21623"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "2",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.16728,0,0,1.16733,198.30893,235.43248"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "3",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.25093,0,0,1.25099,208.91475,246.64871"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "4",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.33458,0,0,1.33466,219.57057,257.91495"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "5",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.41821,0,0,1.41832,230.17368,269.1312"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "6",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.50186,0,0,1.50198,240.8295,280.34741"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "7",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.58551,0,0,1.58565,251.43532,291.61365"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "8",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.66916,0,0,1.66931,262.09113,302.8299"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "9",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.75281,0,0,1.75298,272.74695,314.04611"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "10",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.83644,0,0,1.83664,283.35004,325.31238"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "11",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "1.92009,0,0,1.9203,294.00589,336.52859"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "12",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.00374,0,0,2.00397,304.61169,347.74481"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "13",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.08739,0,0,2.08763,315.26752,359.01105"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "14",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.17104,0,0,2.1713,325.87332,370.22729"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "15",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.25467,0,0,2.25497,336.52646,381.49677"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "16",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.33832,0,0,2.33864,347.13226,392.76303"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "17",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.42197,0,0,2.4223,357.78809,403.97928"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "18",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.50562,0,0,2.50597,368.44391,415.1955"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "19",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.58926,0,0,2.58963,379.04971,426.41174"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "20",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.6729,0,0,2.67329,389.70285,437.67795"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "num" : "21",
                            "Command" : [
                                {
                                    "cmdType" : "Move",
                                    "objectId" : "1",
                                    "transformMatrix" : "2.75655,0,0,2.75696,400.30862,448.89417"
                                }
                            ]
                        },

                    {
                        "num" : "22",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "2.84019,0,0,2.84062,410.96448,460.11047"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "23",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "2.92384,0,0,2.92429,421.57025,471.37668"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "24",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.00749,0,0,3.00795,432.2261,482.5929"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "25",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.09113,0,0,3.09161,442.82922,493.80914"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "26",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.17477,0,0,3.17528,453.48505,505.07535"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "27",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.25842,0,0,3.25894,464.14084,516.29163"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "28",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.34207,0,0,3.34261,474.74664,527.50787"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "29",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.42572,0,0,3.42628,485.40247,538.82733"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "30",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.25221,0,0,3.25276,496.8916,551.22559"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "31",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "3.0787,0,0,3.07925,508.43079,563.67719"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "32",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "2.9052,0,0,2.90575,519.91992,576.17871"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "33",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "2.73169,0,0,2.73224,531.50903,588.63025"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "num" : "34",
                        "Command" : [
                            {
                                "cmdType" : "Move",
                                "objectId" : "1",
                                "transformMatrix" : "2.73169,0,0,2.73224,520.70001,578.25"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With the included js and the snap svg js, it works fine, i just want to be able to put this into a div (or a canvas)!

the result is here:  http://centpourcent.us/cca/05/test.html

HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cjgammon/SnapSVG-Animator/wiki/FAQ

this part:

```
comp = new SVGAnim(
    json,
    width,
    height,
    fps
);
```

replace by (idOfDiv is id of destination div):

```
var container = document.getElementById("idOfDiv");
var comp = new SVGAnim(json,width,height,fps);  
container.appendChild(comp.s.node);
```